# Why would DISTINCT COUNT() return 9 instead of 1?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Z.TITLE) AS COUNT 
FROM QMFILES.MPRLRREQDP Y, 
     QMFILES.MPRLRTYPP Z
WHERE Y.REQUEST_TYPE = Z.ID 
  AND Y.REQUEST_ID = 13033;
```

On this particular result set, if I removed `DISTINCT` and `COUNT()` the result set will return nine rows of the exact same data. If I add `DISTINCT`, I get one row. Adding `COUNT()` I get a result of nine where I am expecting one. I am assuming the order of operations are affecting my result, but how can I fix this so I get the result I want?

NOTE: This is a subselect within a larger SQL statement.

Comment: I think COUNT(DISTINCT Z.TITLE) would have done what you wanted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Z.TITLE)` counts the number of rows with a value for `Z.TITLE` (nine). The `DISTINCT` is superfluous, since the `COUNT` has already aggregated the rows.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Z.TITLE)` counts the number of distinct values in `Z.TITLE` (one).

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. I'll try it in the morning.

Answer (score 3):

The COUNT results in one new record which contains the number of items in the SELECT statement. DISTINCT is looking for the results of the COUNT, which is only that single record after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the title then it should be

```
SELECT Z.Title, COUNT(Z.TITLE) AS COUNT 
FROM QMFILES.MPRLRREQDP Y, 
    QMFILES.MPRLRTYPP Z
WHERE Y.REQUEST_TYPE = Z.ID 
    AND Y.REQUEST_ID = 13033
GROUP BY Z.Title;
```

That will give you something like

```
"Title 1", 9
```

or if you have multiple titles

```
"Title 1", 6
"Title 2", 2
"Title 3", 1
```

with the number being the count of that distinct title.

Comment: As I said, this was part of a larger SQL statement. That was just one of the sub selects. I marked the answer to my question.